# Why does this floating parent calculate it's width before taking sibling into account?

Tags: css, css-float

I am trying to understand why the `.item-wrap` in the css below only calculates it's width *as if `.floatleft2` wasn't there, and yet the `.items` contained by `.item-wrap` clearly are aware that `.floatleft2` is there.

I want the .containingbox to "shrink wrap" the content, but not for the `.item`s to wrap "prematurely" i.e. while there is still extra screen space. (see 'working' fix below).

I have already found the workaround, but what specification in CSS causes this interaction between `.floatleft2`, `.item-wrap`, and `.item` such that the `.item-wrap` width isn't wide enough to incorporate all the `.item`s?

---

> [jsfiddle demo (code reproduced below)](http://jsfiddle.net/3CzXD/14/)
>
> [jsfiddle demo with 'working' inline fix](http://jsfiddle.net/3CzXD/15/)

---

```
<body>   
<h1>float:left on .containingbox, with item-wrap, with floatleft2,  causes premature wrapping of .item</h1>
    <div class="containingbox">
        <div class="floatleft2"></div>
        <div class="item-wrap">
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
            <div class="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
body {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    font: normal 85% arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.containingbox {
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
}
.item-wrap {
    border: 1px solid #0FC;
    height: 3px;
}
.item {
    border: 1px solid #F09;
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    height: 75px;
}
.item::before { content: "item"; position: absolute; }
.floatleft2 {
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you float `.floatleft2` but not `.item-wrap`, `.floatleft2` is taken out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) of the container box ([which gets its own block formatting context from being floated itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)), and `.item-wrap` is laid out as though `.floatleft2` were not there. Since `.item-wrap` is not floated, it behaves like a regular block-level element, using the auto width and stretching to fit the container as per [section 10.3.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth).

The reason why the container is sized horizontally to just fit `.item-wrap` and its floated items is because, when `.floatleft2` is taken out of the normal flow of the container, the container no longer needs to account for the size of `.floatleft2`. It only accounts for the contents of `.item-wrap`, which are themselves also floated.

The width of a floating element, when no explicit width is specified (it uses the auto width), is shrink-to-fit, according to [section 10.3.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width). CSS2.1 does not say *how* to implement shrink-to-fit, but it does say that an implementation *should* use shrink-to-fit. In this case, the container is shrunk to just the minimum width needed to fit the floating items on one line. The width of `.item-wrap` is *never* relevant except that it should stretch to fit within the bounds established by the container, as mentioned above.

What happens then is that when `.floatleft2` is introduced, the floating items float to the left of *that* element (the same fundamental behavior you see when floating the items themselves), regardless of the layout of `.item-wrap` or the container. This causes some of the items to wrap to the next line since neither container element changes its size to account for `.floatleft2`.

Comment: Interesting that shrink-to-fit knows how to fit width the items on one line, *before* they are moved out of place by floatleft2!

Answer (score 0):

you are making the div class from `block` level element to `inline` element.

you should use `float:left`; and remove the `display:inline`

```
.item-wrap {
    /*display: inline;*/
  float: left;
    border: 1px solid #0FC;
    height: 3px;
}
```

Here is the Working Demo. http://jsbin.com/vicusesu/1/edit

Comment: This caused the items to all jump below floatleft2 when the window is smaller instead of what fits on that first line

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have `float: left` on `.float-left2` and `.item` but not on `.item-wrap`.  This effectively removes all floated items from item-wrap (they are floated) while it still keeps the same width as if they were there.

If you add a float (left or right) to your `.item-wrap` you will not have this issue.

Comment: Well, adding float:left on item-wrap causes the whole set of items to jump to its own line when the viewport is small.